# OptaPlanner VRP edge weights need to use actual GPS data instead of Euclidean distance

Tags: graph-theory, optaplanner

I am new to optaplanner. I am trying to modify the vrp example [whether the CVRP or the VRPTW] to supports more than just the Euclidean distance as the edge weight between nodes. I am using the newest release optaplanner 6.0.0.CR5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to handle this. All presume you have a GPS system (such as google maps) that can easily return the distance between 2 points A and B.

Note that's it's the GPS's system responsibility to decide the actual roads to take from A to B (that's not an NP-complete problem and GPS systems have already been optimized for it). OptaPlanner is to decide which order to do A, B, C, D, ... (which is NP-complete).

**A) Calculate the distance at hoc (not recommended)**

Just replace the get `Location.get...Distance(Location)` method with a call to your GPS system.

Disadvantage: normally that method is called thousands of time per second and your GPS system won't return the answer that fast, slowing down your average score calculation enormously.

**B) Precalculate the distance and store it in memory**

In the class `Location`, add a `Map<Location, int> dinstanceMap` to holds the distance to every other `Location`. Fill that `Map` before calling `solve()` and implement `get...Distance()` to just do `return distanceMap.get(otherLocation)`.

Disadvantage: memory scaling: if you have too many customers you'll get a OutOfMemory exception.

Workaround: for each `Location`, only add the 1000 closest Locations in that Map. Filter the Move selectors so it never tries to connect 2 locations which are not in each other's Maps. This might affect the quality of the result though.

**C) Precalculate the distance and store it on disk and cache it in memory**

Same as B), but because the distance matrix is too big, store it on disk. Use caching to only fetch a value from the disk if it hasn't been asked recently.

**Update 2019: Just start from [optaweb-vehicle-routing](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaweb-vehicle-routing)**