# Vehicle routing with Optaplanner

Tags: routes, optaplanner

Has any one tried optiplanner for real world routing problem by using geo location and actual distance to travel?
I am looking for some kind of freeware or some idea that I can leverage on in case some work has already been done on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this has been addressed in following posts

[OptaPlanner VRP edge weights need to use actual GPS data instead of Euclidean distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410972/optaplanner-vrp-edge-weights-need-to-use-actual-gps-data-instead-of-euclidean-di)

and

[Using real distances between points in optaplanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21455751/using-real-distances-between-points-in-optaplanner?rq=1)

For now closing this question.

Comment: Also, Roman just wrote a very interesting blog post about this problem. [Part 1](http://www.viaboxxsystems.de/vehicle-routing-optaplanner) and [Part 2](http://www.viaboxxsystems.de/scaling-vehicle-routing-problem)