# How Can I pass Both TimeMatrix and DistanceMatrix in optaplanner

Tags: java, routes, optaplanner

I am fetching TimeMatrix(N*N) and Distance matrix from google API ,so how to add that in Optaplanner VRP solver.What is the Default vehicle Speed optaplanner is using for routing? Can I change that speed?
[This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410972/optaplanner-vrp-edge-weights-need-to-use-actual-gps-data-instead-of-euclidean-di) explains How to pass actual distance Matrix to the solver,like that can I pass actual Time matrix to solver.Please Help..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21455751/using-real-distances-between-points-in-optaplanner?rq=1 plz check this

Comment: @MaheshwarLigade The question you provided is for adding distance matrix , but I have both distance and Time matrix.So how can I pass both to the problem.BTW thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust the Vehicle Routing example model so a RoadLocation has a separate distance matrix for distance and for time. Then put up a soft constraint for both of them, each with it's own weight. Then you have a weighted function of distance and time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I add a time matrix map in RoadLocation where do I add soft constraint .Do I need to change drl config file for this.